# Is there a simplifying algorith m for a formula in Disjunctive Normal Form?

Tags: propositional-calculus

Apologies if this question has been asked before. Please point me to it. I could not find it.

> Given a propositional formula which is Disjunctive Normal Form, is there an algorithm which outputs an equivalent formula which uses a minimal umber of connectives? The connectives in the output can only be those in $\{ \lnot, \lor, \land \}$.

It is the exclusion of $\implies $ and $\iff$ that makes me think there could be such an algorithm.

---

In an Exercise in *Enderton*'s *A Mathematical Introduction to Logic*, I am required to find a wff that is equivalent to $ ( \lnot p \land  \lnot q \land \lnot r ) \lor ( p \land  \lnot q \land \lnot r ) \lor ( \lnot p \land  q \land \lnot r ) \lor ( \lnot p \land  \lnot q \land r ) $ in which connective symbols ($ \lnot, \lor $ and $\land$ only) occur in less than $5 $ places.

Comment: Maybe it helps to translate the given formula to 'at most one of $p$, $q$ and $r$ is true'.

Answer (score 1):

I've found the answer to the question in Enderton thought I'd put it in here.

The formula essentially represents a case of "disagreeing" with the majority. That is return true if a majority of $p, q, r$ are false and vice versa. So we can consider the formula

$$  \lnot ( (p \land q) \lor (p \land r) \lor (q \land r) ) $$

which will be false when two or more of  $p, q, r$ is true and true when at least two of $p, q, r$ is false.

Now I applied the distributive law to the sub-formula $(p \land q) \lor (p \land r)  $ to obtain the logically equivalent formula

$$ \lnot ( (p \land (q \lor r)) \lor (q \land r) )  $$

which has not more than $5$ of the logical connectives allowed.